# DataAnnotations Type 'Required' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Why does the IDE not recognize the `Required` attribute in the following code?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class ShippingDetails

<Required()> _
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Name As String

End Class
```

The error is:

> Type 'Required' is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll. The `RequiredAttribute` also needs .NET 3.5 or above.

Comment: I want to shoot myself. Although the `Imports` statement does not "yell" at me, I realized that my reference to the actual dll was made in a different project. Thanks for forcing me to look again.

Comment: @Shai Try ReSharper or similar tools, they'll sometimes tell you when you have dll issues.